# cannot get content from bot messages in discord

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to get message content sent by bot in discord. It prints empty message.
And eveything is ok when I send message by myself.
Also it worked well with another bot a few month ago.

Message content intent is enabled in discord ui.

Here is my code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()


DISCORD_TOKEN = 'MY_TOKEN'


intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True


bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}')



@bot.event
async def on_message(message):

    # printing message
    message_content = message.content
    print(message_content)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run(token=DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

Comment: Make sure the bot is online, has the right permissions, and message content intents are also enabled on the developers portal

Answer (score -3):

First problem:

If you use `intents = discord.Intents.all()` that includes every intents so you don't need this:

```
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True
```

Delete these two.

Second problem:

Declear your bot as `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)` You don't need `discord.ext` in it.

Third one is not a problem but unnecessary:

This:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run(token=DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

Can be changed to only:

```
bot.run(DISCORD_TOKEN)
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help. Still empty message

Comment: I'm sorry, none of this are actual problems that solve the question, but rather unnecessary code that does infact not change the codes work. This would be good as a comment but not as an answer to the question

Comment: There is nothing else to change in the code for it to work. I tested it and for me it worked. I changed nothing else then the above... Check your token.

Comment: @Rexy token is okay. It works good with messages sent by me.

Comment: What are the messages it wont work with?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/GxNCM3h first msg by bot. Second msg by me - works good.